# add or subtract from elements in matrices using python

Tags: python, matrix

Using iPython, I want to take a matrix and make it so that if one of the elements is greater than 26, it will subtract 26 from that element until it is true.

Also, if it is less than 0, for it to add 26 until true.

For example:

```
X=([[206, 126,  226,  80, 193,  57, 127],
     [-90, -63, -100, -39, -90, -23, -55],
     [ 31,  26,   37,  17,  35,  13,  26]])
```

I need to take that matrix and make it so all the elements are between 0 and 26 by only adding or subtracting 26 from each element.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this? Can you post that attempt?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the modulo 26 of each element. First of all you need to flatten the list and then perform modulo.

```
>>> a = [i%26 for s in X for i in s]
```

Now you need to restore the original shape of X.

```
>>> Y = [a[i:i+7] for i in range(0,3*7,7)]
```